# OVM: How to reset master password on Oracle VM?

Tags: oracle, virtual-machine

I use Oracle VM (VirtualBox on Linux) on my Mac. The problem is I cannot connect to database.

When I run

```
$ sqlplus
```

I get the message

```
Enter user-name:
```

Username `/as sysdba` is not valid. It gives me

```
ORA-01017: invalid username/password.
```

How can I reset the password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are doing this as root.  You should not be doing anything oracle related as root.

As root:

```
[root@vblnxsrv02 ~]# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
[root@vblnxsrv02 ~]# sqlplus

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Mon Jan 25 16:50:21 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: /as sysdba
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

As the owner of the oracle installation:

```
oracle:tulsa$ id
uid=54321(oracle) gid=54321(oinstall) groups=54321(oinstall),54322(dba) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023

oracle:tulsa$ sqlplus

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Mon Jan 25 16:50:37 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: /as sysdba

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

SQL>
```

Technically, the difference is in that root is not (and should not be) a member of the group 'dba'.  When oracle receives a request to log on a "/ as sysdba", it checks to see if the OS user is a member of the 'dba' group.  Technically you could fix it by making root a member of the group, but that is the wrong approach.  You should never use root for anything that does not absolutely requrie it.  It is simply too powerful.  Using root is like running with scissors in one hand and a loaded gun (with the safety off) in the other.